# Rails: display of array as string in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, string, format

I have a model field that is an array. I can store it and retrieve it from the database with no trouble.

When a user creates or edits this array I want them to see it and edit it as a comma separated list. There are sensible reasons behind my choice to store as an array and to have the user interact with a list, plus they rarely edit the records containing the list/array. 99% of the time they only edit that record once, when they create it, although they may view it many times, those view times the record will not be in edit mode so I am not concerned about a performance hit coming from using serialize.

I know how to split the string into an array of strings, and I know how to join and array of strings to make up a comma separated list.

My dilemma revolves around where to do this split/join? In the controller as private methods called before display/before save, some where in the model, or maybe as a form helper? I've no idea.

Advice would be appreciated.

Comment: One of many ways would be to create a virtual attribute (`my_attr`) in the model that represents the comma separated list. When you get the attribute (show it in a form), the code in the model (`def my_attr`) would do the join. When the attribute gets set in a submit of a form, the code in the model (`def my_attr=`) would split the list up back into an array and assign it to the real attribute(s).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to convert it to text. ActiveRecord::Base Class macro `serialize` is built for such use case - *Saving arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects in text columns*

> Active Record can serialize any object in text columns using YAML. To do so, you must specify this with a call to the class method serialize. This makes it possible to store arrays, hashes, and other non-mappable objects without doing any additional work.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :preferences
end

user = User.create(preferences: { "background" => "black", "display" => large })
User.find(user.id).preferences # => { "background" => "black", "display" => large }
```

Doc: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html
*See serialize part*